# Not being able to connect to mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to connect my app to MongoDB but i get the following error as i run my app:

```
DepracationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.

[MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discover and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to MongoClient constructor
```

I know both above are just warnings but they are stopping my app and no letting me run it.

This is how i am setting the connection to mongodb in app.js:

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
const csrf = require('csurf');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const multer = require('multer');

const errorController = require('./controllers/error');
const User = require('./models/user');

const MONGODB_URI =
  'mongodb+srv://mateoghidini:<PASSWORD>@cluster0.9dernor.mongodb.net/test';

const app = express();
const store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: MONGODB_URI,
  collection: 'sessions'
});
const csrfProtection = csrf();

const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'images');
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + '-' + file.originalname);
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
    file.mimetype === 'image/png' ||
    file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' ||
    file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg'
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');
const shopRoutes = require('./routes/shop');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(
  multer({ storage: fileStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).single('image')
);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'my secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: store
  })
);
app.use(csrfProtection);
app.use(flash());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.session.isLoggedIn;
  res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
  next();
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // throw new Error('Sync Dummy');
  if (!req.session.user) {
    return next();
  }
  User.findById(req.session.user._id)
    .then(user => {
      if (!user) {
        return next();
      }
      req.user = user;
      next();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      next(new Error(err));
    });
});

app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
app.use(shopRoutes);
app.use(authRoutes);

app.get('/500', errorController.get500);

app.use(errorController.get404);

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  // res.status(error.httpStatusCode).render(...);
  // res.redirect('/500');
  res.status(500).render('500', {
    pageTitle: 'Error!',
    path: '/500',
    isAuthenticated: req.session.isLoggedIn
  });
});

mongoose
  .connect(MONGODB_URI)
  .then(result => {
    app.listen(3000);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Is any of the packages that i am requiring above deprecated? Or should i include new lines of code that i am missing?

Comment: Why dont you do what the messages are you telling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember having similar issue, so first of all make sure your `mongoose` version is above `5.7.1`, if it is you can pass the `options` objects suggested from your warning message to your `connect` function like so:

```js
mongoose
  .connect(MONGODB_URI, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
  .then(result => {
    app.listen(3000);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```